# mongodb how to query with nand operator?

Tags: mongodb, operators

I'm using $match of aggregation.
and I tried this.

```
    $match : { 
      $not: {
      'A': false,
      'B': 'condition'
      } 
    }
```

but not work like nand. it works like not A and not B.
How can I query with Not(A and B) ?

Comment: A feature request has been opened for the `NAND` logical operator, see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15577

Comment: you can just use $nor for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $not operator does not invert a complex expression.
You need to use $and or $or for complex expressions.

Using logic rules, we know that the following are identical:

```
    not ( A and B ) = not A or not B
```

Using the MongoDB query language, you would have:

```
db.collection.find({$or:[{"a":{"$ne":false}},{"b":{"$ne":"condition"}}]})

OR simplifying the double boolean:

db.collection.find({$or:[{"a":true},{"b":{"$ne":"condition"}}]})
```

Using the MongoDB aggregation framework, you would have:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{"$match":{$or:[{"a":{"$ne":false}},{"b":{"$ne":"condition"}}]}}])

OR again, simplified to:

db.collection.aggregate([{"$match":{$or:[{"a":true},{"b":{"$ne":"condition"}}]}}])
```

Answer (score 6):

This should fetch you the results

```
{
    $or: [
        {'a': { $ne: 1} },
        {'b': { $ne: 2} }
    ]
}
```

However, this expression did not yield the desired result in my case so I tried this-

```
{
     $nor: [
       {
         $and: [
             {a: 1},
             {b: 2}
         ]
       }
    ]
}
```

Comment: MongoServerError: unknown operator: $nor

Answer (score 2):

there is a very simple trick to create NAND with mongoDB:

```
$nor : { $and [..., ...] }
```

Comment: $nor must be an array, so this will error. mohakjuneja's answer worked for me

Answer (score -2):

you can think other way in mongodb with available options.

```
db.Collection.find({'arrary.a':{$exists:false},'arrary.b':{$exists:false}})
```

hope this will help you...

Comment: sorry I can't understand this. Can you explain what $exists roles?

Comment: means it will result those documents which don't have field A and B.

Comment: My question is not about exist but match a specific value.

Comment: so you can do like this db.inventory.find( { A: { $ne: false },B:{$ne:condition } )