# MongoDB using NOT and AND together

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to negate an `$and` clause with MongoDB and I'm getting a `MongoError: invalid operator: $and` message back. Basically what I want to achieve is the following:

```
query = { $not: { $and: [{institution_type:'A'}, {type:'C'}] } }
```

Is this possible to express in a mongo query?

Here is a sample collection:

```
{ "institution_type" : "A", "type" : "C" }
{ "institution_type" : "A", "type" : "D" }
{ "institution_type" : "B", "type" : "C" }
{ "institution_type" : "B", "type" : "D" }
```

What I want to get back is the following:

```
{ "institution_type" : "A", "type" : "D" }
{ "institution_type" : "B", "type" : "C" }
{ "institution_type" : "B", "type" : "D" }
```

Comment: You want a "NAND Gate" (which has already been asked here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/20810698/782034 )

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You're looking for `NOT (A AND C)`, which is equivalent to `NOT A OR NOT C`:

```
db.collection.find({
  "$or": [
    {"institution_type": {"$ne": "A"}},
    {"type": {"$ne": "C"}}
  ]
})
```

MongoDB also has a [$nor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/) logical operator that "performs a logical NOR operation on an array of one or more query expression and selects the documents that fail all the query expressions in the array", so an equivalent query would be:

```
db.collection.find({
  "$nor": [
    {"institution_type": "A"},
    {"type": "C"}
  ]
})
```

The accepted answer recommends using a `$where` operator, but that is unnecessary here and taxes performance.

Comment: Doesn't your second example using the `$nor` operator query for `NOT A AND NOT C`, rather than `NOT (A AND C)`?

Comment: this is wrong.  You can test this with: 
db.institutionTest.insert({ "institution_type" : "A", "type" : "C" });
db.institutionTest.insert({ "institution_type" : "A", "type" : "D" });
db.institutionTest.insert({ "institution_type" : "B", "type" : "C" });
db.institutionTest.insert({ "institution_type" : "B", "type" : "D" });

db.institutionTest.find({
  "$or": [
    {"institution_type": {"$ne": "A"}},
    {"type": {"$ne": "C"}}
  ]
})

db.institutionTest.find({
  "$nor": [
    {"institution_type": "A"},
    {"type": "C"}
  ]
})
returns only 1 document instead of requested 3

Comment: $nor performs a logical NOR operation on an array of one or more query expression and selects the documents that fail all the query expressions in the array. => $nor is equivalent to `$and: [ { $not: A }, { $not: B } ]`, NOT `$or: [ { $not: A }, { $not: B } ]`

Comment: Nonetheless, I am looking for top-level `$not`, which is actually `$nor: [{[k]: {[op]: v}}]` equivalent to `{[k]: {$not: {[op]: v}}}`. So, I upvote.

Comment: `{ $not: { $and: [A, B] } }` is not equivalent to `{ $nor: [A, B] }` as mentioned by @Kesarion

Comment: @Valen - your `$nor` example is wrong, it should be `{ $nor: [{institution_type:'A', type:'C'}] }`

Answer (score 4):

Not a standard negation that I can see, you would need a [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator styled query with JavaScript:

```js
db.collection.find(function(){ 
    return !( this.institution_type == "A" && this.type == "C" ) 
})
```

Not the best as that scans a whole collection, but the negation in your logic requires this as you need to test both values.

Or the essentially equivalent aggregation operation:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "institution_type": 1,
        "type": 1,
        "notmatched": {
            "$not": {
                "$and": [
                    { "eq": [ "$institution_type", "A" ] },
                    { "eq": [ "$type", "C" ] }
                ]
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$match": { 
        "notmatched": true
    }}
])
```

Only just realized this was also a valid form by including the negation on the inside:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "$or": [
        { "institution_type": { "$ne": "A" } }, 
        { "type": { "$ne": "C" }},
    ]
})
```

Where that essentially negates the combination of "A" and "C" in the same document just as the other logic does with a wrapping "not" condition.

---

### Orig

In MongoDB queries the [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) is actually implicit since that is the default comparison of terms in a query. You only need to use [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) when you are looking for multiple conditions on the same field.

But your query is a simple inequality match:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "institution_type": { "$ne": "bank" },
    "type": { "$ne": "account_type" }
})
```

So you use the [**`$ne`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) operator to negate your terms from a match, where as already stated the [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) is implicit so both conditions must apply.

So with sample data:

```js
{ "institution_type" : "bank", "type" : "account_type" }
{ "institution_type" : "school", "type" : "account_type" }
{ "institution_type" : "school", "type" : "account" }
```

The query only returns the row that does not meet both conditions:

```js
{ "institution_type" : "school", "type" : "account" }
```

Your comment says you wan "OR" which you do not specify in your query as you are using "AND", so perhaps you are expecting that "OR" is implicit which is the opposite of what I have told you is the case.

An [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) condition needs to be explicitly applied:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "$or": [
        { "inititution_type": { "$ne": "bank" } },
        { "type": { "$ne": "account_type" } }
    ]
})
```

Which is actually double negation and would return all results.

Perhaps you mean [**`$nor`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/):

```js
db.data.find({
    "$nor": [
        { "inititution_type": "bank" },
        { "type": "account_type"  }
    ]
})
```

But actually that is logically the same as the first query I gave you.

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to be right. My original query is `NOT (A AND B)`, which should translate to `(NOT A) OR (NOT B)`. The query you've given me is `(NOT A) AND (NOT B)`

Comment: @Stankalank Not sure why you think an OR condition is implied in the syntax in your question `$or` conditions must be explicit as I have additionally shown. So unless you ask for an `$or` the comparison is actually `$and`

Comment: OK, so my original query contains an `(A AND B)` clause, we both agree there. What we disagree on is what happens when you negate that. You're claiming that `NOT (A AND B)` is equivalent to `(NOT A) AND (NOT B)` while I am claiming that it is equivalent to `(NOT A) OR (NOT B)`. de Morgan's laws seem to agree with me on this one http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/de-Morgan%27s-laws

Comment: The last two queries you have are equivalent and correct.

Comment: @Stankalank I'm just helping you get the correct query result. You tried something, it doesn't work, you ask a question and someone answers. Perhaps you should define some data in your question and show the result you expect to achieve. If that is any different from the example that is shown. If you expect help then arguing with people is probably not the way to go.

Comment: Will edit the question to make it more clear! Thanks for you help!

Comment: @Stankalank You may have missed the notifications but there are a few approaches to get your desired result

Comment: Accepted the answer b/c you put in a lot of work. Thanks! TBH, though, the `$or` and `$nor` queries are the best answers. Looping through the whole collection is undesirable and the aggregation framework seems to be a bit overkill for this kind of query.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem, but not solved.

My collection have this itens (**total 17**):

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9d09dff9399554b35f4fc8"), 
    "status" : {
        "codigo" : "1", 
        "msg" : "Ativo"
    }, 
    "extra" : [

    ], 
    "tipo" : "amizade", 
    "vinculo" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d69a8eb0215c92942fd0983")
    }, 
    "vinculado" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d6821c70215c9e5e5fd096b")
    }, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-08T22:12:47.872+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-10-08T22:12:47.872+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9d09dff9399553df5f4fc9"), 
    "status" : {
        "codigo" : "1", 
        "msg" : "Ativo"
    }, 
    "extra" : [

    ], 
    "tipo" : "amizade", 
    "vinculo" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d6821c70215c9e5e5fd096b")
    }, 
    "vinculado" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d69a8eb0215c92942fd0983")
    }, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-08T22:12:47.883+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-10-08T22:13:10.129+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9d0a00f93995da635f4fca"), 
    "status" : {
        "codigo" : "1", 
        "msg" : "Ativo"
    }, 
    "extra" : [

    ], 
    "tipo" : "vacuo", 
    "vinculo" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d69a8eb0215c92942fd0983")
    }, 
    "vinculado" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d6821c70215c9e5e5fd096b")
    }, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-08T22:13:20.310+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-10-08T22:13:20.310+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9d0a44de4e534ba8a1eaf6"), 
    "status" : {
        "codigo" : "1", 
        "msg" : "Ativo"
    }, 
    "extra" : [

    ], 
    "tipo" : "nao-sugerir", 
    "vinculo" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d69a8eb0215c92942fd0983")
    }, 
    "vinculado" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d833a2a7aebc4af5ba378ca")
    }, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-08T22:14:28.445+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-10-08T22:14:28.445+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9d0a48de4e534ba8a1eaf7"), 
    "status" : {
        "codigo" : "1", 
        "msg" : "Ativo"
    }, 
    "extra" : [

    ], 
    "tipo" : "nao-sugerir", 
    "vinculo" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d6821c70215c9e5e5fd096b")
    }, 
    "vinculado" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d82c2e07aebc4305da378b1")
    }, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-08T22:14:32.189+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-10-08T22:14:32.189+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9d0b28de4e534ba8a1eaf8"), 
    "status" : {
        "codigo" : "1", 
        "msg" : "Ativo"
    }, 
    "extra" : [

    ], 
    "tipo" : "amizade", 
    "vinculo" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d6821c70215c9e5e5fd096b")
    }, 
    "vinculado" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d82de827aebc42767a378c6")
    }, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-08T22:18:16.235+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-10-08T22:18:16.235+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9d0b28de4e534ba8a1eaf9"), 
    "status" : {
        "codigo" : "2", 
        "msg" : "Solicitação pendente"
    }, 
    "extra" : [

    ], 
    "tipo" : "amizade", 
    "vinculo" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d82de827aebc42767a378c6")
    }, 
    "vinculado" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d6821c70215c9e5e5fd096b")
    }, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-08T22:18:16.268+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-10-08T22:18:16.268+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9d10eede4e534ba8a1eb0d"), 
    "status" : {
        "codigo" : "1", 
        "msg" : "Ativo"
    }, 
    "extra" : [

    ], 
    "tipo" : "amizade", 
    "vinculo" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d6821c70215c9e5e5fd096b")
    }, 
    "vinculado" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d82755c7aebc49efca378aa")
    }, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-08T22:42:54.790+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-10-08T22:42:54.790+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9d10eede4e534ba8a1eb0e"), 
    "status" : {
        "codigo" : "2", 
        "msg" : "Solicitação pendente"
    }, 
    "extra" : [

    ], 
    "tipo" : "amizade", 
    "vinculo" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d82755c7aebc49efca378aa")
    }, 
    "vinculado" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d6821c70215c9e5e5fd096b")
    }, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-08T22:42:54.822+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-10-08T22:42:54.822+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9dad94f939952d305f4fcc"), 
    "status" : {
        "codigo" : "1", 
        "msg" : "Ativo"
    }, 
    "extra" : [

    ], 
    "tipo" : "amizade", 
    "vinculo" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d69a8eb0215c92942fd0983")
    }, 
    "vinculado" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d82d8fa7aebc42be1a378c2")
    }, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-09T09:51:16.984+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-10-09T09:51:16.984+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9dad94f939957a905f4fcd"), 
    "status" : {
        "codigo" : "2", 
        "msg" : "Solicitação pendente"
    }, 
    "extra" : [

    ], 
    "tipo" : "amizade", 
    "vinculo" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d82d8fa7aebc42be1a378c2")
    }, 
    "vinculado" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d69a8eb0215c92942fd0983")
    }, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-09T09:51:16.998+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-10-09T09:51:16.998+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9dad96f939956a345f4fce"), 
    "status" : {
        "codigo" : "1", 
        "msg" : "Ativo"
    }, 
    "extra" : [

    ], 
    "tipo" : "vacuo", 
    "vinculo" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d69a8eb0215c92942fd0983")
    }, 
    "vinculado" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d82d8fa7aebc42be1a378c2")
    }, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-09T09:51:18.587+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-10-09T09:51:18.587+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9dce0cf939958be25f4fcf"), 
    "status" : {
        "codigo" : "1", 
        "msg" : "Ativo"
    }, 
    "extra" : [

    ], 
    "tipo" : "amizade", 
    "vinculo" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d69a8eb0215c92942fd0983")
    }, 
    "vinculado" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d8354497aebc439a7a378d0")
    }, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-09T12:09:48.619+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-10-09T12:09:48.619+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9dce0cf939958c4b5f4fd0"), 
    "status" : {
        "codigo" : "2", 
        "msg" : "Solicitação pendente"
    }, 
    "extra" : [

    ], 
    "tipo" : "amizade", 
    "vinculo" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d8354497aebc439a7a378d0")
    }, 
    "vinculado" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d69a8eb0215c92942fd0983")
    }, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-09T12:09:48.635+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-10-09T12:09:48.635+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9dce10f9399590a65f4fd1"), 
    "status" : {
        "codigo" : "1", 
        "msg" : "Ativo"
    }, 
    "extra" : [

    ], 
    "tipo" : "amizade", 
    "vinculo" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d69a8eb0215c92942fd0983")
    }, 
    "vinculado" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d685f790215c983e4fd097e")
    }, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-09T12:09:52.994+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-10-09T12:09:52.994+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9dce11f9399564715f4fd2"), 
    "status" : {
        "codigo" : "2", 
        "msg" : "Solicitação pendente"
    }, 
    "extra" : [

    ], 
    "tipo" : "amizade", 
    "vinculo" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d685f790215c983e4fd097e")
    }, 
    "vinculado" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d69a8eb0215c92942fd0983")
    }, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-09T12:09:53.006+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-10-09T12:09:53.006+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9e4afbde4e534ba8a1eb0f"), 
    "status" : {
        "codigo" : "1", 
        "msg" : "Ativo"
    }, 
    "extra" : [

    ], 
    "tipo" : "nao-sugerir", 
    "vinculo" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d69a8eb0215c92942fd0983")
    }, 
    "vinculado" : {
        "colecao" : "atletas", 
        "objeto" : ObjectId("5d80f31e7aebc412dea3789a")
    }, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-09T21:02:51.026+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-10-09T21:02:51.026+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

In this query, returns correct (**4 itens**):

```
db.getCollection("vinculos").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$match" : {
                "status.codigo" : "1", 
                "tipo" : {
                    "$in" : [
                        "amizade", 
                        "nao-sugerir"
                    ]
                }, 
                "vinculo.objeto" : ObjectId("5d6821c70215c9e5e5fd096b")
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

But i need a inverse of this itens:

**1st attempt (No Results)**:

```
db.getCollection("vinculos").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$match" : {
                "$nor" : [
                    {
                        "status.codigo" : "1"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "tipo" : {
                            "$in" : [
                                "amizade", 
                                "nao-sugerir"
                            ]
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "vinculo.objeto" : ObjectId("5d6821c70215c9e5e5fd096b")
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

**2nd attempt (No Results)**:

```
db.getCollection("vinculos").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$match" : {
                "$and" : [
                    {
                        "status.codigo" : {
                            "$ne" : "1"
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "tipo" : {
                            "$nin" : [
                                "amizade", 
                                "nao-sugerir"
                            ]
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "vinculo.objeto" : {
                            "$ne" : ObjectId("5d6821c70215c9e5e5fd096b")
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

**I will need return other 13 itens, any suggestion?**

Answer (score 0):

#### TLDR; You want a NAND Gate...

```
db.getCollection('test').find({ $or: [ {institution_type:{$ne:'A'}}, {type:{$ne:'C'}} ]})
```

... And then go thank (upvote) [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46383363/782034) (not me)

#### or a NOR Gate...

```
db.getCollection('test').find({ $nor: [{institution_type:'A', type:'C'}] })
```

---

#### Longer version...

I couldn't find a [logical operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-logical/) in MongoDB to handle `$nand` logic, so I "built" the logic (see below).

There is an [open feature request](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15577) for a `$nand` operator, but I wouldn't hold my breath (created 2014).

`$nor` can also do what you want, if you invert the `$ne` logic.

(But IMO - it feels like we're bastardising the behaviour - only using the inverse `$not` behaviour, and disregarding the `$and` behaviour of the array... but it works, so it's not wrong).

```
db.getCollection('test').insertMany([
    { "institution_type" : "A", "type" : "C" },
    { "institution_type" : "A", "type" : "D" },
    { "institution_type" : "B", "type" : "C" },
    { "institution_type" : "B", "type" : "D" }
])

// "NAND gate": (NOT A) OR (NOT B) -> correct 3x results
db.getCollection('test').find({ $or: [ {institution_type:{$not:{$eq:'A'}}}, {type:{$not:{$eq:'C'}}} ]})

// or simpler...
db.getCollection('test').find({ $or: [ {institution_type:{$ne:'A'}}, {type:{$ne:'C'}} ]})

// or simpler still...

// "NOR gate": (NOT A) AND (NOT B) -> correct 3x results
db.getCollection('test').find({ $nor: [{institution_type:'A', type:'C'}] })
```